# Firestore Security Rule allowing unauthenticated access only to one collection

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to establish below scenario with the  help of Firestore rules.

How can I let user access 'products' collection without authentication but other collections with authentication? I have tried putting rules as below, but it doesn't work.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // All should be able to access products collection
    match /products {
        allow read;
    }
    // All other collection should only be accessed if user is authenticated.
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `match /products/{document=**}`

Comment: What if the public collection is /shops/{shopId}/products

Comment: Then you probably need `/shops/{shopId}/products/{document=**}`

Comment: @MichaelBleigh, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this will work:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // All should be able to access products collection
    match /products/{allProducts=**} {
        allow read;
    }
    // All other collection should only be accessed if user is authenticated.
    match /{notProducts}/{allNotProducts=**} {
      allow read: if notProducts != "products"
                  && request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```